# best platform for blackberry for screen tinter?

Tags: java, blackberry

i need to build an app for blackberry that will change the background color for all apps

something like this:

http://www.thomson-software-solutions.com/html/screen_tinter.html

is this something i should do in java? i have no experience with programming for PDAs. which compiler would i use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use J2ME (Java Platform, Micro Edition) with the RIM's API. To get started, you might want to pay a visit to RIM's [BlackBerry Developer Zone](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/). They have a development IDE with everything you need to get started.

You also must first understand that coding for mobile platforms is totally different from coding for a PC. What you can do is fairly restricted (by design, hardware creators usually don't want third-party addons to fault the device). I don't think your project is feasible.